# Welche Verben lassen sich mit ähnlich vielen Verbalpräfix wie "legen" kombinieren?

Tags: verb, prefix, morphology

Auf [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A4fix) findet man eine beachtliche Zahl von Präfixen, die sich mit "legen" kombinieren lassen.

```
ab-
an-
auf-
aus
be-
bei-
dar-
ein-
er-
hin-
hinter-
nach-
nieder-
über- (unbetont)
über- (betont)
um-
unter- (unbetont)
unter- (betont)
ver-
weg-
wider-
zer-
zu-
zusammen-
```

Gibt es andere Verben, die eine vergleichbar hohe Anzahl von Kombinationen mit Präfixen erlauben?

Comment: Weitere gängige Kombinationen, die bei Wikipedia nicht erwähnt sind: _festlegen_, _freilegen_, _loslegen_ und _vorlegen_. Ich denke, dass kein anderes Verb ganz an die Kombinationsmöglichkeiten von _legen_ herankommt.

Answer (score 4):

Das Verb "gehen" hat ähnlich viele Möglichkeiten.

```
ab-
an-
auf-
aus-
be-
durch-
ein-
ent-
er-
hin-
hinter-
los-
nach-
nieder-
über- 
um-
unter- 
ver-
vor-
weg-
zer-
zu-
zusammen-
```

Comment: _entgehen_ gibt's auch (_entlegen_ ist leider kein Verb ...); außerdem: Ich geh gleich _los_, kannst Du schon mal _vorgehen?_

Comment: Danke, @HendrikVogt. Wenn Dir noch mehr einfallen, fühl Dich frei sie hinzuzufügen :)

Comment: ~f*c*en und ~b*ms*n lassen sich ebenso kombinieren. ;)

Comment: @userunknown: nieder~f*c*en? o_O

Comment: @user: Mir ist rätselhaft, worauf Du hier anspielst. Ist es mangelnde Einbildungskraft, dass mir nur _durch_ passend erscheint?

Comment: @HendrikVogt: Ich fürchte ja. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ähnlich gut kombinierbar sind:

> stellen, gehen, stehen, setzen, geben, kommen, sehen

Auch noch in derselben Liga, wenn auch weniger:

> brechen, nehmen, sprechen, holen

Comment: Ich würde sagen, dass _nehmen_ genauso gut kombinierbar ist wie _geben_, _kommen_ und _stehen_. Auch in der gleichen Liga: _lassen_.

Answer (score 1):

Schlagen

ab-
an-
auf-
aus-
be-
durch-
ein-
er-
ge-
nach-
nieder-
über- 
um-
unter- 
ver-
zer-
zu-
zusammen-

Comment: Außerdem: _losschlagen_ und _vorschlagen_.

Comment: Und: *wegschlagen*

Answer (score 0):

Drehen

ab-
an-
um-
zu-
auf-
aus-
bei-
ein-
her-
los-
mit-
rum-
ver-
weg-
fest-
nach-
über-
plan-
durch-
herum-
handum-
heraus-
zurück-
zusammen-
rechts-

Und noch eine Handvoll mehr...

Comment: _Handumdrehen_ und _Rechtsdrehen_ kenne ich nur als Substantive. _Plandrehen_ war mir nicht geläufig - muss man Dreher sein, um das zu kennen? _rum-_ ist das gleiche wie _herum-_, bloß umgangssprachlich. (Bei _herdrehen_ denke ich übrigens als erstes an _hin- und herdrehen_.)